# C++ (g++) special characters encoding ('\a', '\b', etc.)

Tags: c++, eclipse, linux-mint, g++4.8

I am using g++ version 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 with Eclipse 3.8 on Linux Mint.

Following example from my C++ book does not work as expected:

```
//bondini.cpp -- using escape sequences
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "\aOperation \"HyperHype\" is activated\n";
    cout << "enter sercret code:________\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b";
    long code;
    cin >> code;
    cout << "\aYou entered: " << code << "...\n";
    cout << "\aCode OK! Commencing Z3!\n";
return 0;
}
```

I get following result when running the program:

[image: output here]

In Eclipse and directory I am using UTF-8 encoding. Why does not '\a' play sound as it should and '\b' does not move the cursor one space back, while '\n' works properly.

**edit**: As I understand it, it is the compiler that makes the mess of it. --> I was wrong, in terminal it works fine, but eclipse 'terminal' does not work.

Comment: It's terminal dependent if the special characters are supported.

Comment: When I run it straight from terminal, it works fine. So it seems it is eclipse "terminal" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you are sending your output. What the destination does with it is entirely in its own hands. So while eclipse might not support these special characters your terminal should.

Comment: That is true, I tried running it in terminal and it worked. However my Eclipse "terminal" is also set to UTF-8 but still shows wrong output. Do you have any idea where could be the problem?

Comment: This is an eclipse implementation so there's really nothing you can do.